# PHP filter json using $GET in URL

Tags: php, json

I want my json be filtered with two rows using `$GET` in the url where I can type something like `http://carkila.esy.es/carkila/user.php?owner=ownerANDstatus=pending` can you please help me fix my code thanks. :)

```
<?PHP
include_once("connection.php");

session_start();

$where = '';
if (isset($_GET['owner']) && isset($_GET['status'])){
$where = " WHERE owner like '%".addslashes($_GET['owner'])."%' AND status like '%".addslashes($_GET['status'])."%'";
}
$query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_cars ".$where." ORDER BY Car_No DESC"; 

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$data[] = $row;
}
 echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this: `owner&status` arguments seperator for a url.

You can also use 
`http_build_query (array('owner'=>'owner','status'=>'pending'))`

to generate `owner=owner&status=pending`